# cannot execute php artisan command [php fatal error[

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-artisan

[image]I have a laravel project I installed the composer 
and run

> composer install

After that I executed the update command

> composer update

on the project's root directory, and during the execution on the command

> php artisan optimize

I got the error shown in the attached image.

When I try to execute any php artisan command I got the same error too.

Error lines

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::check() in C:\xampp\htdocs\projectx\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php:221
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\projectx\app\Exceptions\Handler.php(39): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('check', Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\projectx\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(81): App\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError))
#2 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError))
#3 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\projectx\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 221
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::check() in C:\xampp\htdocs\projectx\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php:221
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\projectx\app\Exceptions\Handler.php(39): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('check', Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\projectx\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(81): App\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException))
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\projectx\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(123): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException))
#3 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleShutdown()
#4 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\projectx\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 221
```

Comment: did you update your laravel version recently?

Comment: Try `composer dump-auto`?

Comment: that won't solve the issue

Comment: @Indra Yes  I updated to the last version ..

Comment: @fskirschbaum this not work

Comment: The framework tries to instantiate all commands preemptively when they are registered so make sure you're not trying to do any strange things in the constructors

Comment: Even I am having the same issue. I am upgrading to 5.4 and any artisan command I provide I get this same error.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to  use the `append_config()` helper method in your environment app configuration file:

```
'providers' => append_config(array(
    'LocalOnlyServiceProvider',
))
```

Comment: You mean \config\app.php ?

Comment: I did, but when I try to execute the command php artisan config:cache I got the same errors

Answer (score 0):

The command `php artisan optimize` has been remove in laravel 5.6 
see more: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade

Comment: So what can I do? composer update trigger it during the update not me. but also, when I try to execute any command starts with php artisan, for example php artisan list, I got the same error

Comment: Replace use Auth; with use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;